# Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259 when including a count and group by

Tags: sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

I get the following when I run the sql script.  Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

The script will run when I remove the Count statement and the group by statement.

```
 DECLARE @sub VARCHAR(100);
 DECLARE @qry VARCHAR(1000);
 DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(250);
 DECLARE @query_ath NVARCHAR(1000);
 DECLARE @query_attachment_filename NVARCHAR(1000);
 DECLARE @tab char(1) = CHAR(9);


 SELECT @sub = 'Daily Absence Report';
 SELECT @msg = 'Please refer to the attached spread sheet for the 
  report.'

  SELECT @query_ath = 'select dbserver.dbo.tabeA.some_field,
                        count(case dbserver.dbo.tabeA.field when a then 1 
  end) as count_1
  from dbserver.dbo.tabeA
   where a condition is met
  group by dbserver.dbo.tabeA.some_field';

 SELECT @query_attachment_filename = 'test.csv';

  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
      @profile_name = 'email',
 @recipients = 'myemail@something.edu',
 @body = @msg,
 @subject = @sub,
 @execute_query_database = 'dbserver',
 @query = @query_ath,
 @query_attachment_filename = 'ath_absences.csv', 
 @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
 @query_result_header = 1,
 @query_result_width = 256,
 @query_result_separator=@tab,
 @quer`enter code here`y_result_no_padding = 1;

 Msg 22050, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
 Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259.
```

Comment: You're missing a comma.

Comment: also better to give a column name for the count: count(case dbserver.dbo.tabeA.field when a then 1 
  end)  AS a_count

Comment: JacobH I wrote the code in a hurry and over looked the comma. It is in the script that I am running.

Comment: PeterHe, I the count named in the script that I wrote.  When I take the count and group by out the script runs without error.  That is what is confusing to me.